# Error in assigning values to an element of 4D array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

New to python and trying to resolve the below -

I am trying to assign a value to a 4D array element, but I get the error "'int' object does not support item assignment". I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

```
#Some calculation to get val
X[i,j,k,l] = val
```

This is the first time X is defined/assigned value in the code. The value 'val' is a float, but I don't think this is affect the assignment.

Could anyone explain what might be causing the error? Thanks.

Comment: "This is the first time X is defined/assigned value in the code." Are you sure? If X didn't exist prior to this line, I'd expect the error to be `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`, not `'int' object does not support item assignment`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I'm not sure why I'm getting the error": because `X` is an int. But without context, we can't tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that X is already defined with type int when you try to assign the value. 
A good way to avoid such errors is to follow PEP8 naming conventions [Link to PEP8](http://pep8.org/#naming-conventions)

In your case, be sure to declare X before the assignment with numpy.zeros or numpy.empty.